# Using a View like to make a separator in a Widget

Tags: android, view

I want to use a vertical separator in my `Widget` but the element `View` is prohibited with `Widget`.

Are they other solutions to have something like this ?

```
<View
    android:layout_width="2px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#496185"/>
```

Comment: Can you share your entire XML file?

Comment: `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `ImageView`, `TextView`, etc. You could use any of them, really, with nothing set on them but a background color. Alternatively, you could use `layout_margin*` attributes on the "real" `View`s to put the desired space between them, and set the root `ViewGroup`'s background color to that of your separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `RelativeLayout` instead of `View` :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#496185"/>
```